# Magento semi ignores System > Config > Catalog > SEO setting

Tags: seo

So I have set Magento not to include category URLs into the product URL and it works fine when browsing site but if I visit the "old" URL, it does not redirect to the categoryless page.

Is this normal? 1.9.2.1

Example:

https://www.airytea.com/organic-imperial-white-peony-white-tea.html

https://www.airytea.com/buy-organic-white-tea/organic-imperial-white-peony-white-tea.html

Moz.com indexed both and I have no idea how and I can't find a way to replicate where did it grab the second URL from but my biggest issue that is still works and it should not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is default behaviour and only references how Magento generates the URLs when it is called upon within a block/template.  It doesn't stop any of the other URLs being available and working.

`Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` -> `addUrlRewrite()`

My suggestion would be to canonical your product pages back to the non-categorised version.  In Magento 1.9.2.1, you can find this option under System | Configuration | Catalog | Catalog | Search Engine Optimizations -> Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories.

Please test that this geneates the correct URL on your store.  If it does, leave this enabled, and Google will eventually de-index the alternate URLs.